# Fetching nested objects in Realm is slow

Tags: android, realm

I have two RealmObject classes, NodeToUser and Task:

```
class NodeToUser extends RealmObject {
    int id;
    Task task;
    String otherStuff;
}

class Task extends RealmObject {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

Now, I want all Tasks, where NodeToUser.otherStuff == "foo".

All I came up with, is doing a Query on NodeToUser like so:

```
RealmResults<NodeToUser> nodes = realm.where(NodeToUser.class)
    .equalTo("otherStuff", "foo")
    .findAll();
```

And then go over the result and collect the actual Tasks.

```
List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (NodeToUser n : nodes) tasks.add(n.getTask());
```

However, this iterating over the result and collecting the objects I really want, is very slow -- just a rough value: **for 100 NodeToUser objects it takes 2 seconds** on my device.

**Question**: Is there a better/faster way, or some way to create the query so that I can get the list of tasks directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class NodeToUser extends RealmObject {
    int id;
    Task task;
    String otherStuff;
}

class Task extends RealmObject {
    int id;
    String name;

    @LinkingObjects("task")
    private final RealmResults<NodeToUser> fromNodes = null;
}
```

then

```
RealmResults<Task> tasks = realm.where(Task.class)
        .equalTo("fromNodes.otherStuff", "foo")
        .findAll();
```